# Cannot return null for non-nullable fiel error with graphene form mutations

Tags: django, django-forms, graphene-django

I'm trying an example of graphene-django with forms. But I get next error:

`graphql.error.base.GraphQLError: Cannot return null for non-nullable field [MyMutationPayload.name].

I'd tried set values in return expression inside perform_mutate function. It does not work if request does not perform all variations.

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(min_length=10)
  age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
  birth_date = forms.DateField()

class MyMutation(DjangoFormMutation):
  class Meta:
    form_class = MyForm

  @classmethod
  def perform_mutate(cls, form, info):
    print('ok')
    return cls(errors=[], name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'), age=form.cleaned_data.get('age'), birth_date=form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date'))

class Mutations():
  my_mutation = MyMutation.Field()

class Mutation(Mutations, ObjectType):
  pass

ROOT_SCHEMA = Schema(mutation=Mutation)
```

Query

```
mutation customMutation($data: MyMutationInput!){
  myMutation(input: $data){
    name
    age
    birthDate
    errors{
      field
      messages
    }
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

Variables

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Cristhiam",
    "age": "-29",
    "birthDate": "1990-04-06"
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field MyMutationPayload.name.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "myMutation",
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "myMutation": null
  }
}
```

Mutation result should show all errors or all form values.

Answer (score 1):

It worked:

```py
    @classmethod
    def perform_mutate(cls, form, info):
        super().perform_mutate(form, info)
        return cls(errors=[], **form.cleaned_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your Code As Follows**

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(min_length=10)
    age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    birth_date = forms.DateField()


class MyMutation(DjangoFormMutation):
    class Meta:
        form_class = MyForm

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, **input):
        print('ok')
        return cls(errors=[], name=input.get('name'), age=input.get('age'), birth_date=input.get('birth_date'))

class Mutations(ObjectType):
  my_mutation = MyMutation.Field()

class Mutation(Mutations, ObjectType):
  pass

ROOT_SCHEMA = Schema(mutation=Mutation)
```

**input** is the argument that is passed down to the mutation according to their documentation.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. Graphene doc says "If the form is valid then the class method perform_mutate(form, info) is called on the mutation. Override this method to change how the form is saved or to return a different Graphene object type.". The "mutate_and_get_payload" method is used for custom mutations.